# How to access static files in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on node js, where I have the following directories: `C:\wamp64\www\Scrapper`. In the `Scrapper` folder, I have:

- `/Controllers/main.js`
- `/Public/index.html`
- `/server.js`

What I did is, I have included the `main.js` in the `index.html` as:

`<script src="/Controllers/main.js"></script>`

Also, I have declared these two folders as static in node js `server.js` file which is located in the main directory i.e. `/Scrapper`. When I run the app, it says:

`http://localhost:8080/Controllers/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

The way I declared the static files in `server.js` is :

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/Public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/Controllers"));
app.use(body_parser.json());
```

I don't know what the problem is. All I want is to include the `main.js` file in the `index.html`. It's a client site script which should run within that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you have declared a static folder like

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/assets`))
```

and inside `assets`, you have `images` folder

[image]

then you can access the files i.e.

```
localhost:8080/images/koala-1550238924102.jpg
```

and in your case you need to do this

```
localhost:8080/main.js
```

Comment: `path.join` is not necessary since you use a template string as single argument...

Answer (score 1):

You can look in detail [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/Public"));
app.use('controllers', express.static(__dirname + "/Controllers"));
```

Access files;

```
http://localhost:<port>/index.html
http://localhost:<port>/controllers/main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const publicStaticDirPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
app.use(express.static.(publicStaticDirPath));
```